# How to display a phone number in an iphone webapp?

Tags: iphone

I have a webapplication that runs on an iphone and I would like to display a phone number on it. How can I make this so that when the phone number is clicked then the phone number will be dialled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **tel:** url scheme.  Mobile Safari will automatically set the link.